# Neovim not showing all possibilities in LSP

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

I have a fairly standard version of Lunar Vim.

While coding, the LSP shows potential matches but, I can't get it showing **all** the potential matches. I just shows 1 single entry for each name.

Take a look at the following image:
[image]

It shows `isUndefined` from `lodash` while what I'm interested is on the same function from `lodash-es` (also installed and working in the project).

I've also seen this behaviour with other objects like `User` which just shows the object from the ORM instead of the object from the project.

Is there anything I can do for the LSP to show all the potential objects?

Many thanks.